# Chrome dev tools shows download status as canceled for dynamically generated file in Grails app

Tags: grails, download, extjs4.1, google-chrome-devtools

I have a requirement to generate an Excel file from some parameters sent in the request.  Everything appears to be working fine, but if I open up Chrome's dev tools, it marks the download in red and the Status column shows "(canceled)". I can still open up the downloaded file perfectly fine.

I also used the net-internals to log further information but I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for.

The final log messages show:

```
[st=52] DOWNLOAD_ITEM_COMPLETING
                       --> bytes_so_far = "6656"
                       --> final_hash = "BLAHBLAHBLAH....."
[st=80]    DOWNLOAD_FILE_DETACHED
[st=80]    DOWNLOAD_FILE_CLOSED
[st=93]    DOWNLOAD_ITEM_FINISHED
                       --> auto_opened = "no"
[st=94] -DOWNLOAD_ITEM_ACTIVE
```

The Grails / apache poi code to generate the file is fairly simple:

```
def downloadFile() {
    def cellData = params.data

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel")
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=myfile.xls')
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)

    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook()
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("My Sheet")
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0)
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(cellData)

    ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wb.write(outByteStream);
    byte [] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();

    response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
    response.outputStream << outArray
}
```

And finally, in our Javascript app (we're using ExtJS 4) I've tried multiple methods of downloading the file:

1. Appending a hidden form to the document (with action = the "downloadFile" controller method) and calling form.submit()
2. Appending a hidden iframe to the document (with src = the "downloadFile" controller method)
3. Using Ajax.request with isUpload: true and form: hiddenFormElement

All three successfully download the file, but Chrome still shows status canceled.

I noticed this warning in the Chrome console:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this line

```
render(text: outArray, contentType: "text/xls", encoding: "UTF-8")
```

after this

```
response.outputStream << outArray
```

Comment: fabio thanks for the response.  I tried this, but it's still giving me the same error.  The only difference is I have "response.outputStream.flush()" after response.outputStream << outArray.  I put your render line after that.  If I remove the flush() call, I get an exception: Message: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Answer (score 0):

Adman sorry forgot to flush, the code below is working on my chrome

```
def xls() {
def cellData = params.data

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel")
response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=myfile.xls')
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)

Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook()
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("My Sheet")
Row row = sheet.createRow(0)
row.createCell(0).setCellValue(cellData)

ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
wb.write(outByteStream);
byte [] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();

response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
response.outputStream << outArray
response.outputStream.flush
render(text: outArray, contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel", encoding: "UTF-8")
```

}